# Rails 3 - ActiveRecord Find When Album Name Equals

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I've got a photo gallery Rails 3.0 app where Photos belong to Album. There are multiple Albums. I'm struggling trying to figure out how to select my Photos from an Album where I have passed in the Album name as a parameter. What is the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You haven't really provided much here, your models will be useful.

Assuming you have:

```
class Album < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :photos
end

class Photo < ActiveRecord::Base
end
```

And Album has a name field.

Then you can do:

```
@photos = Album.find_by_name(params[:name]).photos
```

Comment: Depending on how you plan to use the photos you could eager load them with the find on the album. @album = Album.find_by_name(params[:name], :include => [:photos])